# How do I compute the determinant of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

> For $n \geq 2$, compute the determinant of the following matrix:
>   $$
>  B =
>  \begin{bmatrix}
>   -X     &  1     & 0      & \cdots &  0      & 0      \\
>    0     & -X     & 1      & \ddots & \vdots  & \vdots \\
>   \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &  0      & \vdots \\
>   \vdots &        & \ddots & \ddots &  1      & 0      \\
>   0      & \cdots & \cdots & 0      & -X      & 1      \\
>   a_0    & a_1    & \cdots & \cdots & a_{n-2} & (a_{n-1} - X)
>  \end{bmatrix}
> $$

I am thinking of just multiplying the matrix along the diagonal but I'm not sure if that would work.

Comment: Laplace and induction?

Comment: The first part is $-X\cdot \det(\text{sub-matrix})$ and the second part is $1\cdot \det(\text{sub-matrix of } 1)$

Comment: Characteristic polynomial of a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)